# how to get the most updated result in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query, get the results for different people, but for every people, they have  different results, how can i get oldest result for each people, the following pic is for one specific people.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select <<your fields>> 
from (select t.*, row_number(partition by <<person_id>> order by OLD_ACTIVE_DT desc) as rn
      from <<your query>> t) vw
where vw.rn = 1
```